# kernel customisation using menuconfig with Yocto

Tags: kernel-module, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

Hope you all are doing well

I'm working with the Yocto project having **dunfell** branch
As a hardware perspective, I'm using STM32MP1dk1 board with **meta-st-stm32mp** layers

My ultimate goal is to generate the custom image via enabling some drivers using menuconfig
Now, **the problem is, after menuconfig it's successfully generating the image but unfortunately, in custom image I'm unable to find the loadable kernel modules!**

This is what I'm doing

1. Manually set the required drivers by using menuconfig GUI tool

```
  bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
```

2.Generate the default configuration

```
bitbake -c savedefconfig virtual/kernel
```

- also verified the drivers, which I have set in to the menuconfiig
- drivers exist in defconfig

3. copy defconfig in to the custom-layer

```
  /meta-customer/recipes-kernel/linux/files/
```

4. Updated linux-stm32mp_%.bbappend asper the default configuration

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI += "\
               file://0001-stm32mp157a-dk1-i2c-add-dts.patch \
               file://0002-stm32mp157a-dk1-add-ltdc-dts.patch\
               file://defconfig\
"
# Applying the default configuration


KERNEL_DEFCONFIG_stm32mp1 = "defconfig"
```

5. Updated locakl.conf to load the module automatically during the boot

```
# Adding kernel modules for the USB WiFi drivers

IMAGE_INSTALL += "kernel-module-r8188eu \
                  linux-firmware-rtl8188 \
                  dhcp-client \
                  iw \
                  wpa-supplicant \
                  wireless-regdb-static"

# Autoload WiFi driver on boot
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "r8188eu"
```

6. Then i done bake the image

```
bitbake core-image-minimal
```

Problem statement :

1. During the building of the image, I can find the logs to build the modules, which I'd set erlear !
2. core-image-minimal.menifest seems not updated, as i verified using grep "modules which i set"
3. After flashing the image on sd card & booting on ab board /lib directory missing all loadable modules!
4. Even, wpa-supplicant is not working, which i have installed with image

Guys, can you advice what's baking wrong here!
All comments & suggestions welcome

Thanks,
Mahendra Sondagar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and the first solution that worked for me was:

1. Find the default defconfig
2. Create `do_configure_append()` in your .bbappend that copies your custom defconfig and overrides the default one in the WORKDIR

After some time I've switched to another approach. I've simply started to manually add and commit changes to the default defconfig and add them as patches to .bbappend.

Both ways have pros and cons so choose whatever works for you.

P.S. There is another approach to add **configuration fragments** and to add them like patches to the default defconfig, but I've haven't tried it